# Malware on Java update for mac os x

Tags: java, macos, malware

I am working on a mac os x computer. I was asked by a Java automatic update.
I have answered to remind me later this update.

And Safari opened this url: prefmgr-cookie.truste-svc.net

Do you think it is a malware or do you have ever see that when updating Java for mac os x ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this was a java update dialog and not e.g. a browser notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prefmgr-cookie.truste-svc.net` is a service from [TrustArc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrustArc) (formerly TRUSTe, hence the domain name) which provides services for websites so that they can manage privacy management processes. Basically, they host the cookie compliance stuff, for example. Various research shows that they suck at their job, so a TRUSTe logo on a site is mostly a sign said company is throwing money at the problem and not actually willing to adhere to standards and laws, but that's beyond the technical nature of Stack Overflow.

It is not malware.

Note that 'java automatic update' isn't a thing. java is shipped by some party, and there are many offerings: AdoptOpenJDK ships them. So does oracle (but they don't want to, and you should probably not have oracle's offering). So does azul, amazon, even microsoft.

The updater, if there is such a thing, is installed and controlled by the party that shipped it to you, but you did not specify which java you installed, so going much further than this answer is difficult without knowing what you have.

You also don't need java installed unless either [A] you are a developer or [B] you are trying to run software built by some entity that is woefully out of date. Java apps should be shipped self-contained (not requiring you to separately install 'java') and this isn't hard to do either.

Answer (score 0):

Googling this URL points to the company TrustArc (https://trustarc.com/), which provides an integration for websites, where the website visitors can manage their cookie preferences (e.g. only allow cookies which are necessary and disable additional tracking cookies on a specific website). So the URL itself is from a major company in that area, and can IMO be trusted.

For the reason, why this would be opened when delaying the Java update i can only speculate, possibly because the fact, that you delayed the update is stored locally in a cookie and thus the updates has to forward you to that page so that you can manage the settings.